# jquery - multi-select dropdown and single select dropdown on same page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, multi-select

I'm using the jQuery dropdown that was developed by Eric Hynds. 
[Eric Hynds Multi-select](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)

I want to have a multi-select dropdown and a single select dropdown on the page. 
I thought I could reference it this way:

```
 $(function () {

  $("select").multiselect({
    selectedList: 4
  });

  $("#ddlYear").multiselect({
    multiple: false,
    selectedList: 1
  });
});


 <div class="multiselectlist">
     <select id="msStatus" multiple="true" runat="server"/>
 </div>

 <div><select id="ddlYear" multiple="false" runat="server"/></div>
```

I populate the dropdowns from code-behind getting data from the database. 
Even though I set the single select (ddlYear) to not be multiple it still shows up as a multi-select dropdown.

Is there a way for the two type of dropdowns to exist on the same page?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("#msStatus").multiselect({
    selectedList: 4
  });

  $("#ddlYear").multiselect({
    multiple: false,
    selectedList: 1
  });
```

Comment: Hi Jayantha, 
Your solution didn't work.  If i do that change all dropdown lists turn into multi select lists.  For some reason it is only accepting the $("select").multiselect({
    selectedList: 4
  });
?

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with that plugins or you can use either of these 2 plugins

[Jquery Plugins 1](http://www.jquery4u.com/drag-and-drop/18-jquery-drag-drop-plugins/)

[Jquery Plugins 2](http://www.jquery4u.com/drag-and-drop/10-jquery-drag-drops/)

It seems there's an error on your script

Comment: I tried it in regular HTML instead of the aspx page. 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){


 $("#demo").multiselect({
  multiple: true,
  header: "Select an option",
  noneSelectedText: "Select an Option",
  selectedList: 1
 });
 
 $("#demo2").multiselect({
  multiple: false,
  header: "Select an option",
  noneSelectedText: "Select an Option",
  selectedList: 4
 });
 

 
});
</script>
This works.  THe KEY here is, i have a runat=Server so i can populate the list from code behind. I think that is the problem. I wonder how I can get around this?